# Wordpress indent with copy-paste code

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a blog with awesome tutorials, when I copy my code correctly indent and paste it in the pre tag, the indent dissapears.

An example, I have this code and copy it:

```
<section id="sobremi" class="sobremi parallax-container">
            <div class="parallax"><img src="img/parallax.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <h4 class="deep-orange-text text-darken-4">sobre mí</h4>
                <hr class="deep-orange-text text-darken-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 center">
                        <div class="card small blue-grey darken-1">
                            <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                                <img class="activator" src="img/sobremi.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-content">
                                <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Mr. 8-Bits <i class="mdi-navigation-more-vert right"></i></span>
                                <p>
                                    <a href="#">twitter</a>
                                    <a href="#">facebook</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-reveal">
                                <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title <i class="mdi-navigation-close right"></i></span>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Then I open wordpress and edit my article, I paste the copied text in a  and the indent dissapears:
[image]

I have to indent my code manually...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the Text tab and paste it there and it will keep the HTML formatting as well as execute the code. What you are doing now is pasting it into the WYSIWYG and it will convert the code to HTML entities so it doesn't execute.